# Freshchat SDK Integration (Xamarin:Android) -> Com.Freshchat.Comsumer.Sdk.Beans.CalendarDay Error

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am trying to integrate freshchat on my app. I got last freshchat Android SDK version here https://github.com/freshworks/freshchat-android/releases.
Then, I converted freshchat .jar file into dll using  Xamarin Android Class Library but, when I build this library project , I get this error:
[image: CalendarDay error]

[image: Com.Freshchat.Consumer.Sdk.Beans.CalendarDay]

I have tried with InputJar and EmbeddedJar buil action and I get same error.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images

Answer (score 2):

(1) Build Action for .jar should be InputJar.

(2) Transforms/Metadata.xml should contain these lines:

[image: please add these lines]

```
<metadata> <add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.beans']/class[@name=
'CalendarDay.TimeSlot']">
<method name="compareTo" return="int" abstract="false" native="false" synchronized="false" 
static="false" final="false" deprecated="not deprecated" visibility="public">
<parameter name="p0" type="java.lang.Object" /> </method> </add-node> </metadata>
```

Comment: <metadata>
 <add-node path="/api/package[@name='com.freshchat.consumer.sdk.beans']/class[@name='CalendarDay.TimeSlot']">
  <method name="compareTo" return="int" abstract="false" native="false" synchronized="false" static="false" final="false" deprecated="not deprecated" visibility="public">
   <parameter name="p0" type="java.lang.Object" />
  </method>
 </add-node>
</metadata>

Comment: set Release option and
Rebuild your LibProject then go to release folder to get .dll, reference this .dll to consume sdk functions.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I do not get errors when I rebuild my libProject(freshchat) but, I am facing more issues when I try to use this library.  :( The documentation does not help a lot.

Comment: @JohanEcAv FreshChat sample which is developed in xamarin native https://github.com/idotene/Xamarin-Freshdesk-Android
can you please check this. (here you dont need to get dll from jar...already there)

Go to helpdesk.com, login and get domainurl, appid, appkey under Admin/Chat>
use in above sample.

Comment: Hi @sumit, welcome to stackoverflow.
I noticed that you added the code in the comment section, I wanted to tell you that it's always recommended to have the code in the answer; as there is code identification (more readable in different color), plus it can be copied/edited later on.
Thanks

Comment: @sumit mmm I got confused now because what I want to integrate is freshchat not helpdesk. :(

Comment: Please go to url: https://support.freshchat.com/en/support/solutions/articles/50000000207-freshchat-android-sdk-integration-steps#4.1-Conversations

and scroll to bottom then press no on (did this article found helpful) then provide all details there.
their team will support you on email or direct call about sdk issue fixes.

Comment: @JohanEcAv are you able to consume freshchat sdk in forms? if not then I can provide you solution which I built. please reachout me sam58016@gmail.com

Comment: @sumit  if you could share git repository, I would be thankful and I consider it would help others with this implementation.